# Convert libvirt xml into qemu command line

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I created a VM using virt-manager and I can edit that xml using virsh edit, but I would like to ask you if there is way of converting libvirt xml into qemu command line. I've found that someone else made the same question sime time ago :

https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/dh9iyo/convert_libvirt_xml_into_qemu_command_line_and/

and the user jkhsjdhjs says :

For converting libvirt xml to qemu command line you can just start the vm with libvirt. libvirt will start a qemu process with a whole lot of command line arguments which you can then save. Since libvirt just starts a qemu process they should perform exactly the same.

ok,but how ? I would like to understand how to start the vm with libvirt,so that I can see every options included in the qemu command.

I tried with :

```
virsh dumpxml win10

virsh domxml-to-native qemu-argv win10.xml

error: internal error: invalid PCI passthrough type 'default'
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the question asks how to generate the `qemu` command line
from `virsh`, one might just look at the process run once the VM(domain) has started. However to answer the question more correctly, this might be the proper command:

`virsh domxml-to-native`

This is because `domxml-to-native qemu-argv --domain [name_of_vm]` will not start the VM, but only create a command line that would do that. As the [virsh](https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#domxml-to-native) man page says:

> ```
> domxml-to-native format { [--xml] xml | --domain domain-name-or-id-or-uuid }
> ```
>
> Convert the file *xml* into domain XML format or convert an existing *--domain* to the native guest configuration format named by format. The *xml* and *--domain* arguments are mutually exclusive. For the types of *format* argument, refer to [`domxml-from-native`](https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#domxml-from-native).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look in the QEMU log-file for that guest. These log-files are located on the host in the folder `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/DomainName`

You can see the executed **/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64**...  command in the log.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get your machine running in VirtManager and then go to a terminal window and list all the processes with the ps command:
`ps -fA`
or
`ps -fA | cat`.
(`cat` will make the long strings wrap in the a console).  Then you can find the *qemu* process and extract the text of the command issued by VirtManager, since it merely calls qemu to run the machine.