# Running VMs and virsh command from qemu build from source

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I am trying to build QEMU from source using the instructions given [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux). I am trying to implement a research paper which adds features to the migration mechanism of QEMU and so I need a custom build(from source) of QEMU. I need cli commands to be able to do everything because I am automating the entire build and running of Vm and migration using Ansible. I am able to install the dependencies and reach to the screen where I get the option to install the OS in the qcow2 image that I create using the following 2 commands.

- `cd  qemu/build`
- `./qemu-img create -f qcow2 test.qcow2 16G`
- `x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -drive if=virtio,file=test.qcow2,cache=none -cdrom ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`
  And I get this screen which allows me to install OS.

[install window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5rUv.png)

However once installed, I am not able to figure out how to run the installed OS from the qcow2 image?
Moreover I want to run migration commands to migrate VM from one host to other. Using the official QEMU(downloaded from software center) I installed `virt-manager` and `libvirt` and run the migration using

- `virsh migrate --live migrate-server --persistent --verbose --copy-storage-all --desturi qemu+ssh://clarkk@vm02/system`

Again I want to be able to do all this using the command line on custom build of QEMU (building QEMU from source code).

Thanks

I have tried to search online for results like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638844/how-to-start-qemu-vm-from-command-line), but they are not for custom build of QEMU, because on custom build you dont have access to virt-manager and libvirt.

Documentation aren't very beginner friendly either, or I have not been able to look at the right place.

Comment: `I am not able to figure out how to run the installed OS from the qcow2 image?` remove `-cdrom ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` from your qemu command line? And see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973902/libvirt-custom-emulator-path).